# MS Access query criteria based on specific field in another query

Tags: ms-access

I have a MS Access Database that identifies all the members in MemberTable. These members are assigned supervisors in that table.

I also have a ManagerTable that identifies managers of sections.

For use in tables I have all individuals referenced to the AutoNum in the MemberTable so updates can be made easily.

I have QueryA that pulls all the information relating to the "Member", including their "Supervisor", to generate a report.

I have QueryB that pulls the "Section" they work in, a "LeadManagerA", and a "LeadManagerB".

These Lead Managers are also the supervisors of some individuals.

I am attempting to create a query that uses the criteria for "Supervisor" to only display the members whose supervisor is "LeadManagerA" of a specific "Section".

Essentially my issue is, I don't want to use the specific name or Autonumber for "LeadManagerA" because that can change. And I can't figure out how to call a specific field from a specific row in QueryB for use in criteria.

MemberTable:

| AutoNum | Member | Supervisor | Item1 | Item2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Bob | 2 | Green | West |
| 2 | Susan |  | Blue | North |
| 3 | Tim | 1 | Blue | South |
| 4 | Jane | 1 | Red | North |
| 5 | Sam | 3 | Red | West |

ManagerTable:

| Section | LeadManagerA | LeadManagerB |
| --- | --- | --- |
| TeamA | 1 | 2 |

QueryA:

| Member | Supervisor |
| --- | --- |
| Bob | Susan |
| Susan |  |
| Tim | Bob |
| Jane | Bob |
| Sam | Tim |

QueryB:

| Section | LeadManagerA | LeadManagerB |
| --- | --- | --- |
| TeamA | Bob | Susan |

QueryICantFigureOut: (Criteria calling members whose Supervisor is TeamA LeadManagerA without using “Bob” as that individual can change and I would have to rewrite the criteria everytime it changed.)

| Member | Supervisor | Item1 | Item2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Tim | Bob | Blue | South |
| Jane | Bob | Red | North |

Comment: Edit question to show sample data and desired output as text tables. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: That is clearly unclear :-)

Comment: Edited to include example tables.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. I was attempting to generate a query using multiple sources that access originally wouldn't allow. I had to make a query and create a join relationship with LeadManagerA and Supervisor.